# Write and Read struct to Binary File in C (netbeans) doesnt work

Tags: c, netbeans, binaryfiles, fwrite, fread

```
## MY STRUCT ##


    typedef struct clientes{
        int cod_cliente;
        char name[100];
        char country[100];
        char city[100];
        char email[100];
        int nif;
        char n_passporte[50];
        char n_carta_conducao[50];
        char telefone[50];
    }CLIENTE;


    typedef struct Elem{
        VEICULO info_veiculo;
        CLIENTE info_cliente;
        ALUGADO info_alugado;
        struct Elem *seguinte;
    }ELEMENTO;
```

---

```
## FUNCTIONS ##



       int saveBinaryCliente(ELEMENTO *iniLista){
             ELEMENTO *aux = NULL;
            FILE *fp = NULL;
            int res=0;

            fp = fopen("clientes.dat", "wb");

            if(fp == NULL){
                printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro clientes!\n");
                return -1;
            }

            for(aux=iniLista; aux!=NULL; aux=aux->seguinte){

        /*
                printf("%i %s %s %s %i %s %s %s %s\n", aux->info_cliente.cod_cliente, aux->info_cliente.nome, aux->info_cliente.pais, aux->info_cliente.cidade, aux->info_cliente.nif, aux->info_cliente.n_passporte, aux->info_cliente.n_carta_conducao, aux->info_cliente.email, aux->info_cliente.telefone);

        */
```

*Receives every parameter until this printf above*

```
                res = fwrite(aux, sizeof(CLIENTE), 1, fp);
            }

            fclose(fp);
            printf("Saved %i register clientes!\n", res);
            return 0;
        }

        int readDataCliente(ELEMENTO **iniLista){
            CLIENTE aux;
            int res=0;
            FILE *fp = NULL;

            fp = fopen("clientes.dat", "rb");

            if(fp == NULL){
                printf("Error reading file clientes!\n");
                return -1;
            }

            while (!feof(fp)){
                res = fread(&aux, sizeof(CLIENTE), 1, fp);

                if (res){
                    inserirCliente(&(*iniLista), aux);  
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
            }
```

---

```
## OUTPUT ##
```

**LISTING BEFORE CLOSING WITH 1 CLIENT INSERTED**

```
            1 nuno portugal porto 23421342 ASDFA0942 ASDF-434 ssss@hotmail.com +351093856273
```

---

```
             **AFTER CLOSING PROGRAM AND SAVE TO BINARY FILE**

                *****************************************************
                *                MENU  CLIENTES                     *
                *****************************************************
                *                                                   *
                *   1 - INSERT NEW CLIENTE                          *
                *   2 - CHANGE INFO CLIENTE                         *
                *   3 - LIST CLIENTES                               *
                *****************************************************

                Choose your CHOICE: 3
                0    0    
                0    0
```

strange fact...all seemed to work before. Dunno why doesnt work now and it also saves when I dont insert a client and reads it.                 I have been poking my head for a while so i decided to ask you guys for your help, thank you.

Comment: Consider what you're writing. It would help a great deal if you made your program short and self contained, not a bunch of blocks. Read [mcve] for help with that.  In your write function `ELEMENTO *aux = NULL; fwrite(aux, sizeof(CLIENTE), 1, fp);`, and your read `CLIENTE aux; fread(&aux, sizeof(CLIENTE), 1, fp);` You can see these aren't the same thing can't you? `CLIENTE` isn't even the first element in `ELEMENTO`. `&aux->info_cliente` could be what you want in the write.

Comment: thank you for your enlightment, sorry about the writing just  wanted to make things more clear. I tried what you said and it worked but at the same time writes a  0    0  for each cliente inserted any way to fix that? @RetiredNinja

Comment: Based on the code you've shown, how would anyone know what menu option 3 is or does? That's why we ask for a [mcve].